# Android - Preview resizes when recording video

Tags: android, video, camera, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

In an app that I work on, I have an area where there is a video recording preview to record video.  I have the following code to start the preview:

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);

Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0);

parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
parameters.setVideoStabilization(false);

mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
mCamera.startPreview();
mCamera.unlock();
```

For my MediaRecorder, I have the following setup code:

```
if (mMediaRecorder == null) mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3072 * 1000);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(60);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

For some reason, after I start recording my video, the preview resizes itself, appearing "zoomed in".  I tried some of the solutions posted by users asking the same question, but those solutions did not work.  Apparently I need to set the preview size to a 16:9 aspect ratio in order to get it to work properly.  Does anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that video recording of 1280x720 will be supported on all devices. You should iterate over [supported video recording sizes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes()) and choose one that you like best. You can use [getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()) for the video recording size that is recommended for the specific device.

Instead of picking the first preview size returned by  getSupportedPreviewSizes(), you should choose the one that suits you best. In all practical cases, you can expect that the same size can be found in getSupportedVideoSizes() and getSupportedPreviewSizes() lists<sup>**1**</sup>.

You can choose any size, not necessarily one of 16:9 aspect ratio. In the special rare case when you cannot find a satisfactory match between supported video and preview sizes, you should choose the sizes that have the same aspect (i.e. width/hight) ration. E.g. 1280x720 and 640x360.

Note that the video preview **View** (usually, SurfaceView), should also have the same aspect ratio (but not the same size) as the preview size you choose, e.g. you can choose preview of 1280x780 and view size of 1180x720. Otherwise, the preview on your screen will be distorted (too fat or too narrow).

<sup>**1**</sup> *by the book, on some devices, getSupportedVideoSizes() may return **null**. Then, you should use the list returned by getSupportedPreviewSizes()*.